# How do I unlink my register with login for firebase?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am currently trying to make a workable app using expo react native and I encounter some issues while doing it.
My issue is before, I followed a youtube guide to code my login and register on the same page in the application and I find it being too simple. So I want to make it look more like the modern login/register page. Thus I try to create a link from the login page to the register page by the button `Don't have an account?`.  This page worked as it created a account for me when I clicked the button `register` but at the same time, it auto log in the user (newly created) straight away. In the function for handling this sign up, `navigation.replace("Login")` was in the funtion but it does not seem to work.
What I intended to do is to after successfully registering, it will direct me to the login page where the user has to key in the new created details at the login page to login.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options= {{ headerShown : false }} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
        
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import { KeyBoardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'


const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe
    })


    const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Logged in as :' , user.email);
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
    }    
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView  //To prevent keyboard from blocking the writing area
        style={styles.container}
        behavior = "padding"
    >  
        <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <Text>Email:</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={text => setEmail(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
            />
            <Text></Text>
            <Text>Password:</Text>         
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText ={text => setPassword(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry //Hide password
            />         
        </View> 
        {showError && <View style={styles.error}>
          <Text>Incorrect username or password</Text>
        </View>}        
        <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleLogin}
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View> 
        <Text></Text>
        <View style = {{flexDirection:"row"}}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = { () => navigation.navigate("Register")}
                style = {styles.text}
            >
                <Text style={styles.text}>Don't have an account?                 </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                //onPress = {}
                style = {[styles.text]}
            >
                <Text style={styles.text}>Forget Password?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
           
        </View> 
                          
    </KeyboardAvoidingView> 
  )
}

export default LoginScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ //To make the text area for username and password to be center. If not it will be at the top left hand corner
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width: '80%'
    },
    input:{ //Not working?
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 10, //make edge more circle
        marginTop: 5, //Spacing between the input boxes

    },
    buttonContainer:{
        width: '60%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    button:{
        backgroundColor: '#32CD32',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 15, //Making the button enlarge in horizontal and vertical
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center', 

    },
    buttonOutline:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 5,
        borderColor: '#008000', 
        borderWidth: 2, //Without the width, the colour won't show
    },
    buttonText:{ //For the login button
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    buttonOutlineText:{ //For the register button
        color: '#0782F9',
        fontWeight:'700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
   error: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderRadius:10,
      marginTop: 5,
      padding: 16,
      textAlign: 'center'
   },
   text:{
       color: '#0000FF',
       fontStyle: 'italic',
       marginTop: 5,
   }
})
```

RegisterScreen.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { useState } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const RegisterScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        try {
        if (email && password) {
           setShowError(false);
           const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
           console.log('Registered as :' , user.email);
           navigation.replace("Login")
          }
        } catch (error) {
           console.log({error});
           setShowError(true);
        }
    }
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView  //To prevent keyboard from blocking the writing area
        style={styles.container}
        behavior = "padding"
    >  
        <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <Text>Email:</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText ={text => setEmail(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
            />
            <Text></Text>
            <Text>Password:</Text>         
            <TextInput
                placeholder = "Password (Min: 6 chars)"
                value={password}
                onChangeText ={text => setPassword(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
                secureTextEntry //Hide password
            />         
        </View> 
        {showError && <View style={styles.error}>
          <Text>Username or password not valid</Text>
        </View>}        
        <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {handleSignUp}
                style = {styles.button}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>                            
    </KeyboardAvoidingView> 
  )
}

export default RegisterScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width: '80%'
    },
    input:{ //Not working?
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 10, //make edge more circle
        marginTop: 5, //Spacing between the input boxes

    },
    buttonContainer:{
        width: '60%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    button:{
        backgroundColor: '#32CD32',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 15, //Making the button enlarge in horizontal and vertical
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center', 

    },
})
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth)
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
  }
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Email: {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={handleSignOut}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
    width: '60%',
    padding: 15, //Making the button enlarge in horizontal and vertical
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center', 
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  
  buttonText:{ //For the login button
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight:'700',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
})
```

The part that deals with the listener

```
import {useNavigationState} from '@react-navigation/native'


const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const routes = useNavigationState((state) => state.routes);
    const currentRoute = routes[routes.length - 1].name;

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user && currentRoute == 'Register'){
                console.log(currentRoute)
                navigation.replace("Login")
            }
            if(user && currentRoute == 'Login')
          {
              console.log(currentRoute)
              navigation.replace("Home")
          }
        })

        return unsubscribe
    })
```

Alternative method:

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';



const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    let isFocused = useIsFocused;


    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user && isFocused){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe
    })
```

According to the logs,
[image]

How do i read this? The above logs came out when I clicked register

Comment: Are you landing to `App Open -> LoginScreen -> Register Screen`  ? or `App Open -> Register` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This page worked as it created a account for me when I clicked the
> button "register" but at the same time, it auto log in the user (newly
> created) straight away.

By using the JS SDK createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method the newly created user is automatically signed in when the method call is successful. You cannot prevent that.

So if you want to avoid the redirection you need to remove the `navigation.replace("Login")` line. If you don't want the user to be signed in you could immediately call the `signOut()` method (technically speaking the user is signed in for a very short time and then signed out).

Comment: Oh i didnt know it is something that cannot be prevented. Thanks for the suggestion and I have tried it. It worked but is there some way to not show it to the user? Because now whenever I register, the page goes to the homepage for like a sec and goes back to login page. To a user, it might seem the app is buggy i guess?

Comment: This is an effect of your navigation, not of Firebase (see Kailash answer). You can very well signin a user without redirecting him/her.

Comment: Hey @calvinlin, did you have the time to look at the proposed answer?

Comment: Hey @Renaud Tarnec, thanks for checking in. I forgot to mark your answer but I have used your suggestion for the app I am doing currently as it worked nicely

Answer (score 0):

In your LoginScreen you have put

```
 const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })
```

which is a Kind of listener and listening to authentication state change. So as you are doing a registration the firebase auth state is getting changed and listener getting called and then you are landing to HomeScreen. This explanation will come into Picture only if you have navigation stack likewise -> `App Open -> LoginScreen -> RegisterScreen`.

If you make your navigation likewise -> `App Open -> Register -> LoginScreen`, You will not auto logged into the app. Because you haven't navigated to the LoginScreen and that listener not become active.

Even though if you are facing the same problem, then kill the application and restart it.

If you do not want to alter your navigation flow though then you will have to put some condition here in below given code :

**Fetch current Route likewise : -**

```
      import {useNavigationState} from '@react-navigation/native';

      //Inside your LoginScreen
      const routes = useNavigationState((state) => state.routes);
      const currentRoute = routes[routes.length - 1].name;

auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
           //Some handling to move on which screen
           //You can put a check on currently active route here
           //based on that you can navigate accordingly
          if(user && currentRoute == 'Login')
          {
              //navigate to HomeScreen
          }
        })
```

**Alternative to currentRoute :**

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

//inside component 
let isFocused = useIsFocused;

 const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user && isFocused){
                 //It means Login is focused 
                 //means we should redirect to HomeScreen from here 
             }
    })
```

**Alternative 2 :**

```
const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false); 


const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(isLogin){
                navigation.replace("Home")
            }
        })

const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
    if (email && password) {
       const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
       setIsLogin(true);
       console.log('Logged in as :' , user.email);
      }
    } catch (error) {
       console.log({error});
       setShowError(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. My idea is for the app to load with Login page when running. User then has the options of 1. login, 2. click the button 1 to register new acc, 3. click button 2 to reset password. If user click 2nd button, it is directed to another page to register. At this page, when user click register (assuming its successful), account will be created in firebase and for the app, it will direct back to login page for the user to key in the newly created acc to log in. I tried the method you have provided but how do i deal with the currentRoute variable?

Comment: @CalvinLin I've edited the answer to fetch currentRoute

Comment: Thanks @Kailash but am I doing something wrong here? It still doesn't work. I have editing the post with my current code at the bottom

Comment: have you tried killing the app, I mean remove from background as well. because if you'll on refreshing the listeners will keep on listening again, once you kill the app all the listeners will be unsubscribed automatically.

Comment: add a log for  `currentRoute`  in listener. And see when you register what will you be getting over there. And check the same for Login as well.

Comment: Yup I have stop the app from running and rerun it. But it is still the same though

Comment: I have added 1 alternative to currentRoute in the answer, please check

Comment: Hey, thanks for the alternative but is it possible to help me see what is wrong with my code as the issue is not solved? I have updated the post at the bottom.

Comment: check for Alternative 2. 

The issue is  - when your login screen is opening, it will start listening to the AuthStateChange. And then you will move on to the register screeen, still in the background the listener is active and listening to AuthStateChange. So as you are registering the Auth State is getting changes and you are getting navigated to the register screen.

Comment: Hmm how should I correct this to do what I intended to do?